# "Церковь" — с какой буквы писать?

Tags: орфография, семантика, прописная-строчная

С какой буквы пишется слово "церковь": с большой или маленькой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если речь идет об архитектурной постройке, то с маленькой: *церковь Иоанна Крестителя*. Если же речь о религиозной организации, то все слова полного названия пишутся с большой буквы: *Русская Православная Церковь*.

Answer (score 1):

В церковно-религиозных и религиозно-философских текстах в названиях православных церквей все слова названия, кроме предлогов, действительно пишутся с прописной буквы. Однако в обычных текстах написание подчиняется общим орфографическим правилам: в названиях конфессий с прописной буквы пишется первое слово. Верно: 
Русская православная церковь, 
Армянская апостольская церковь, 
Римско-католическая церковь и пр.